# NEST Camera WiFi security disruption

Tags: wifi

Last week one of my NEST WiFi cameras was knocked offline for about 90 seconds. Before this comms loss, we see from the video that someone was using a flashlight and walking towards the camera before losing network communication. To our dismay, we did not learn of this until the next morning when we found our vehicles were broken into. Cash, guns, bicycles, and other personal items were stolen during this event. I would like to know how to duplicate this scenario using an Android or iPhone. Our neighbours (using a Ring Camera) caught the perp walking straight into their camera view while holding what appears to be an Android or other large smartphone. Since their Ring Cam didn’t crash, the perp backed up slowly and retreated from the scene.

Comment: probably a WIFI jammer? https://www.hackster.io/kedarnimbalkar/diy-wifi-jammer-with-esp8266-and-mobile-app-28be5c

Comment: I had a friend tell me about having stuff stolen from his car. When I asked how badly was the car damaged, he said it wasn't. "Wow, they were able to unlock your car?" I exclaimed. "Oh it wasn't locked," he said. He insisted that since it was in his driveway on his property he shouldn't have to lock it! A few months later it happened again. He still refuses to lock his car. Most security mechanisms, only help keep people honest. WiFi cameras are not high tech security, nor are cars high security containers for cash and guns.